# What is the simplest way to install vim on OS X with Arabic enabled?

Tags: macos, vim, arabic-support

Is there a way I can easily install vim with `--with-features=huge` or something along those lines?

It's not clear to me how I can do this using HomeBrew. Is there a way I can do this that doesn't involve downloading and compiling from source, or is that pretty much the only route?

Answer (score 0):

[MacVim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim) has `+arabic`. It is the only reasonable way to get a proper Vim on MacOS.